# my INSERT query not working

Tags: mysql, insert

i dont know why but these values are not going into my database.these is my code.

```
<?php
define('INCLUDE_CHECK',true);

require '../database/connect.php';

session_name('user');
session_set_cookie_params(2*7*24*60*60);
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit']=='Submit')
{   

$stdID='CC13051';
$itemCODE='00';
$pckgeID='1';
$condition='qwe';
$duration='5';
$status='Not Approved';

mysqli_query($link,"    INSERT INTO storage_details(stdID,itemCODE,pckgeID,cndition,duration,status)
                    VALUES(

                        '$stdID',
                        '$itemCODE',
                        '$pckgeID',
                        '$condition',
                        '$duration',
                        '$status',

                    )");
if (mysql_errno()) { 
die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

}
?>
```

mysql_err didnt give out anything.or am i using it in the wrong way?

Comment: There is a comma after '$status$' in your query which shouldn't be there.

Comment: omg thanks.i didnt notice it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i forgot to remove the comma after $status. thanks to @Tobias Baumeister for pointing it out.

```
mysqli_query($link,"    INSERT INTO storage_details(stdID,itemCODE,pckgeID,cndition,duration,status)
    VALUES(

           '$stdID',
           '$itemCODE',
           '$pckgeID',
           '$condition',
           '$duration',
           '$status', <-- this comma should not be here

           )");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqli_query($link,"    INSERT INTO storage_details(stdID,itemCODE,pckgeID,cndition,duration,status)
                    VALUES(".$stdID.",".$itemCODE
```

You are including you PHP variables in SQL as strings, change to include as PHP variables and concatenate them into SQL using `.`

Comment: I normally also do it like you say because it looks better, but I don't think that this is necessary :) His mistake was a comma in the query which shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are not connecting to database.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("dbName");    
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit']=='Submit')
```

By

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
```